# How to turn this LINQ query to lazy loading

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading

I would like to make a certain select item to lazy load latter in my linq query. Here is my query

```
var posts = from p in context.post
            where p.post_isdeleted == false && p.post_parentid == null
            select new
            {
                p.post_date,
                p.post_id,
                p.post_titleslug,
                p.post_votecount,
                FavoriteCount = context.PostVotes.Where(x => x.PostVote_postid == p.post_id).Count() //this should load latter
            };
```

I have deleted the FavoriteCount item in the select query and would like it to ba added later based on certain conditions. Here is the way I have it lazy loaded

```
if (GetFavoriteInfo)
{
     posts = posts.Select(x => new { FavoriteCount = context.PostVotes.Where(y => y.PostVote_postid == x.post_id).Count() });
}
```

I am getting a syntax error with this the above query. How do I fix this

Answer (score 2):

When you delete the `FavoriteCount` in the earlier query, the anonymous type that gets assigned to `posts` doesn't have that field anymore; then in the second query you're creating *another* anonymous type that *only* has a `FavoriteCount` in it - so when you try to re-assign that to `posts` you get an incompatible types error.

One way to do this would be to leave the `FavoriteCount` in the first query, but make it `FavoriteCount = -1` (or some other value to indicate it hasn't loaded yet), and then in the second one you can do:

```
posts = posts.Select(p => new { // reassign existing stuff, 
                                p.post_date,
                                p.post_id,
                                p.post_titleslug,
                                p.post_votecount,
                                FavoriteCount = context.etc.etc. 
                              });
```

You have to do the reassignment because anonymous types are immutable; one way around that would be to make a `PostInfo` class with those fields, then you can just set the `FavoriteCount` in the second query.

Comment: I am a newbie at this..Would you have an example of reassignments?

Answer (score 1):

1.- the type that you are projecting on the first var is not the same type on the second assigment since first one is an anonymus type

you can try this

```
var posts = from p in context.post 
            where p.post_isdeleted == false && p.post_parentid == null 
            select new 
            { 
                p.post_date, 
                p.post_id, 
                p.post_titleslug, 
                p.post_votecount, 
                FavoriteCount = GetFavoriteInfo?context.PostVotes.Where(x => x.PostVote_postid == p.post_id).Count():null //this should load latter 
            };
```

Comment: I had the same thought - but L2S translates this into a SQL case statement and the execution plan in SSMS shows it scanning the PostVotes index regardless of whether GetFavoriteInfo is true or false.

Answer (score 1):

This [**blog entry**](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/02/12/LINQToSQLTutorialsLazyLoadingPropertiesPerformance.aspx) will help you. One more thing, you can enable/disable lazy loading by using the following property of Data Context object.

```
context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
```